# Copy/Paste Data with Cell References (VBA)

Tags: vba, excel, copy-paste

I'm trying to copy data from one file into another. First, I'd like to find the last row/column in the source file and use that information to copy the data. However, I can't seem to get the code to copy/paste with the references to the last row and column used. Here's what I currently have:

```
Dim G7_Tab_Name As String
   G7_Tab_Name = "G7"
Dim wkbDest As Workbook
   Set wkbDest = ActiveWorkbook
Dim SheetToCopy As Worksheet

LastInputRow = wkbSource.Sheets(1).Cells(Cells.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
LastInputColumn = wkbSource.Sheets(1).Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
Set SheetToCopy = wkbSource.Sheets(1)
CopyRange = Range(SheetToCopy.Cells(LastInputRow, 1), SheetToCopy.Cells(1, LastInputColumn))

'Check if any existing data
If Len(wkbDest.Sheets(G7_Tab_Name).Range("A1").Value) > 0 Then
    wkbDest.Sheets(G7_Tab_Name).UsedRange.ClearContents
    CopyRange.Copy _
    Destination:=Range(wkbDest.Sheets(G7_Tab_Name).Cells(LastInputRow, 1), Cells(1, LastInputColumn))
    Else
       CopyRange.Copy _
       Destination:=Range(wkbDest.Sheets(G7_Tab_Name).Cells(LastInputRow, 1), Cells(1, LastInputColumn))
End If
```

I'm pretty sure that I'm not capturing the correct range in my CopyRange definition, but I don't know why. In this case, `lastRow=27` and `lastColumn=13`. So, I thought that the range would define as `"A1:M27"`.

I'm defining these ranges as such because I need to loop through multiple files and copy data from the first sheet in each. This code will be included in a larger For loop to hit each file (once I can get it to copy/paste!)

Comment: A quick note: You didn't give a sheet for the final destination range. It's just `Range(wkbDest.Sheets()...`.  Same with your `Cells()` and `Columns.Count`. uses.  Put the worksheet (and workbook, if necessary) before those too. Otherwise, with multiple books/sheets, VBA can get confused.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Didn't I specify the worksheet for my final destination range when I say `wkbDest.Sheets(G7_Tab_Name)`. Same thing for `Columns.Count` when I say `wkbSource.Sheets(1)`?

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you use `Cells()`, `Range()`, `Columns()`, `Rows()`, etc. make sure you let VBA know what worksheet you expect that to be used on,
otherwise , it 'll use the ActiveSheet, which can cause errors.  You did this in some places, but not others. Below I've done a mix of using `With` statements
to make life easier for those sheets with long names.  Read through the below and see if you can see what I did. Let me know if you have any questions!

```
Sub t()

Dim G7_Tab_Name As String
G7_Tab_Name = "G7"
Dim wkbDest As Workbook
Set wkbDest = ActiveWorkbook
Dim SheetToCopy As Worksheet
Set SheetToCopy = wkbSource.Sheets(1)

With sheetToCopy
    LastInputRow = .Cells(.Cells.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    LastInputColumn = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
End With

CopyRange = SheetToCopy.Range(SheetToCopy.Cells(LastInputRow, 1), SheetToCopy.Cells(1, LastInputColumn))

'Check if any existing data
Dim destWS  As Worksheet
If Len(wkbDest.Sheets(G7_Tab_Name).Range("A1").Value) > 0 Then
    wkbDest.Sheets(G7_Tab_Name).UsedRange.ClearContents
    Set destWS = wkbDest.Sheets(G7_Tab_Name)
    CopyRange.Copy Destination:=destWS.Range(destWS.Cells(LastInputRow, 1), destWS.Cells(1, LastInputColumn))
Else
    CopyRange.Copy Destination:=destWS.Range(destWS.Cells(LastInputRow, 1), destWS.Cells(1, LastInputColumn))
End If

End Sub
```

You did this in places, but not everywhere. I.E: 
`LastInputRow = wkbSource.Sheets(1).Cells(Cells.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row`

You correctly told the *first* `Cells()` which sheet to use, but VBA does not "remember" anything, so the next `Cells.Rows.Count` will be on the Active Sheet, which isn't necessarily your `wkbSource.Sheets(1)` sheet.  Change that line to 
`LastInputRow = wkbSource.Sheets(1).Cells(wkbSource.Sheets(1).Cells.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row`

(Note: This may not solve your issue, but it will absolutely help tighten up the code and leave room for fewer errors).

Edit: Try replacing your `CopyRange` with this:

```
With sheetToCopy
copyRange = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(LastInputRow, LastInputColumn))
End With
```

This will make a range from A1 to the last row in the last column.

Edit2: It's not clear from the code you posted how you declared `CopyRange`, but you should do it like this:

```
Dim CopyRange as Range
Set CopyRange = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(LastInputRow, LastInputColumn))
```

Comment: Thanks for the words of advice. I've updated my code to match yours. However, like you said, the issue still remains. I'm fairly confident it has something to do with how I'm using `LastInputRow` and `LastInputColumn` in my `CopyRange` definition and in the destination line.

Comment: @kschindl - Can you expand on the issue a little more? Let's say the last Row in column A is 1000, and the last Column is Z - you expect `CopyRange` to be (as your code is now) say `A1000:Z1`?  You might have that backwards. Try using the line in my edit.

Comment: Yeah, that would be the expectation. The issue is that no copying/pasting is happening. I put in a `CopyRange.Select` line to see what range was being used, but I saw that no range was selected when I stepped through the code.

Comment: @kschindl - Oh, I think I see why. In my edited code, just do `LastInputRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row` (leave out `Cells`)?  When stepping through the code, do your last Row and last Column variables get set correctly?  Another quick note, `Sheets(1)` isn't necessarily the same as `Sheets("Sheet1")`.

Comment: I edited my `CopyRange` to your suggestion, which makes way more sense. Still no copying/pasting happening though. I also changed my destination lines to match: `Destination:=DestWS.Range(DestWS.Cells(1, 1), DestWS.Cells(LastInputRow, LastInputColumn))`. I can see my last Row/Column are set correctly when debugging (27/13 respectively).

Also, I know `Sheets(1)` isn't the same. I'm intentionally referring to the first sheet in the workbook.

Comment: @kschindl - Oh!! How did you declare `CopyRange`?  See my most recent edit.

Comment: Just as you have it defined. Also, why is it invalid to say `SheetToCopy.CopyRange.Select` when `CopyRange` is a defined range? I'm trying to validate that `CopyRange` has been set correctly.

Comment: `invalid to say SheetToCopy.CopyRange.Select` not invalid. Just poor form.

Comment: @kschindl - You can't really do that, because `CopyRange` has the worksheet already in the variable.  Just use `CopyRange.Select`.  You can't do something like `Sheets("Sheet1").Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A10")` which is what calling `SheettoCopy.CopyRange` is trying to do (does that make sense?)

Comment: lol that's what I get for jumping in half way. Ignore me. Listen to Batman.